# Image Gallery with JSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, gallery

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
"data": {
"ImageSetting": [
  {
    "image_name": "Image 1",
    "image_small": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/d98b276a10f874a67e87edcbe0bfbd2414b62c625f7af6f4c5cc7819259709d3ab39.jpeg",
    "image_big": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/8d580953e8a48c90a8ea3219fd526aa5cb5ac4302161a7c0ba24af6f2be65a233346.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image 2",
    "image_small": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/7ddc15916bd7a8733847c2e9e68202ba0764a969125ebaf862b7ea34d7bac7171e21.jpeg",
    "image_big": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrd14cmu9.cloudfront.net\/1799ed1b6eebf9eb8d1b92de04e8468bc3a7f6ab427863b1e859ds67f3fb4a786dd2.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "image_name": "Image3",
    "image_small": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/b93073d02ed5b0d58c99ddea739c72f6df303a47d4fb7e16829fe61f7c62547b6e3.jpeg",
    "image_big": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/d1e030713f6a0214223f770fe0e6bd9200a2d2ca8da94acde2419064164a1e83f49.jpeg"
  }
]
}
```

So basically with this structure I can show some Images in my App. Now I want to get different galleries with sub-galleries and images beside it. This could be one possible structure:

**Here is the Image snap shot**

[image: FileStructure]

I don't know how to get this done in JSON (Array inside Array?) and I don't know how to parse this in Android. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post second json string which u want to parse

Comment: I don't have the second one yet, since I don't know how to structure it with the different arrays :S

Comment: go through this link :- [Json parsing reference](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) here you got perfect example for JSON parsing in Android.

Comment: Well the problem is not the Android Parsing but the structure of the JSON itself...

Answer (score 0):

Oke let me start of with the JSON itself first. 
It's missing a closing } at the end (maybe you just forgot to copy it) and you do not have an ' array in array' , you've got an object 'data' with an array of objects 'ImageSetting'.

The easiest way to parse this is with GSON, and with that you can cast it directly into an object by just adding a few annotations.

Basically you just need 2 simple classes:

```
public class data{

@SerializedName("ImageSetting")
public Collection<ImageSetting> imageSettings;

}
```

and

```
public class ImageSetting{

@SerializedName("image_name")
public String image_name;

@SerializedName("image_small")
public String image_small;

@SerializedName("image_big")
public String image_big;

}
```

Next all you'd have to do is let GSON do the mapping for you:

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
```

You can get the GSON lib/jar from: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Use Array inside Array. Likewise in your example:

```
{
"data": {
"ImageSetting": [
  {
    "image_name": "Image 1",
    "image_small": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/d98b276a10f874a67e87edcbe0bfbd2414b62c625f7af6f4c5cc7819259709d3ab39.jpeg",
    "image_big": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/8d580953e8a48c90a8ea3219fd526aa5cb5ac4302161a7c0ba24af6f2be65a233346.jpeg"
  },
  [{
    "image_name": "Image 2",
    "image_small": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/7ddc15916bd7a8733847c2e9e68202ba0764a969125ebaf862b7ea34d7bac7171e21.jpeg",
    "image_big": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrd14cmu9.cloudfront.net\/1799ed1b6eebf9eb8d1b92de04e8468bc3a7f6ab427863b1e859ds67f3fb4a786dd2.jpeg"
  },{
    "image_name": "Image3",
    "image_small": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/b93073d02ed5b0d58c99ddea739c72f6df303a47d4fb7e16829fe61f7c62547b6e3.jpeg",
    "image_big": "https:\/\/d2vx3xrdmu9.cloudfront.net\/d1e030713f6a0214223f770fe0e6bd9200a2d2ca8da94acde2419064164a1e83f49.jpeg"
  }]

]
}
```

...and so on for each subfolder, until you reach at the base element (Image). In this case once you parse the whole JSON, You'll get Array within array. & if it an array you can treat it as like folder & subfolder. If it is an image. You can directly use the Image to show in the table.

I hope you understood it. Let me know if any query...

Comment: But how can this Array inside the Array have a name like "Folder 1" and more Image Objects inside?

Comment: In this case.. You need to check if the object is an array, then put the "name" key for folder name & put a key "Data" for the contents... Its just a logical part depends upon the data to you want to put into it.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough about what I need to do. I want to get an Array "Folder 1" inside the "ImageSetting" Array and some Objects like "Image 1", "Image 2" and "Image 3" beside it...